# Ignore default snippet in Sublime Text

Tags: code-snippets, sublimetext2

I've created my own custom version of the `html.sublime-snippet` adding in a doctype and some meta tags and saved it in the `User` directory.
Now, when when I try to trigger my snippet both the default version and my custom version show up as options.
Is there any way to semi-permanently disable the default snippet so only my version is available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was bothered by Python's default snippet for `@property`. I found working solution [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=44783#p44783). Your would be similar:

- In .config/sublime-text-2/Packages copy the `HTML` folder to (for example) `HTML Customized`.
- Hose/Edit out the snippets that offend you in `HTML Customized`.
- Add `HTML` to the `ignored_packages` entry in the preferences to disable the standard `HTML` snippets.

**Without catch!**

Someone called *marcuso* posted this solution on Sublime Text forum. He deserves all glory. (And also *Matt York*, who mentioned the thread in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889312/ignore-default-snippet-in-sublime-text#comment15847617_11893771)).

Answer (score 1):

Options:

1. You can change the `tabTrigger` of your new snippet
2. You can change the `tabTrigger` of the default snippet
3. You can comment out the `tabTrigger` line of the default snippet:

   `<!-- <tabTrigger>html</tabTrigger> -->`

The catch: when you update ST I believe it will overwrite any changes made to the default configuration files. So, if you comment out the `tabTrigger` in the default snippet it will be uncommented after your next upgrade of ST.

Comment: Thanks for the answer however none of these options are perfect. I know there's a way to 'ignore_packages' in the preferences, if only there was a way to ignore a snippet. If there are no other answers I'll accept yours and go with option 1.

Comment: Looks like [you're not the only one](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=7232) with this problem. There is also a [feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/117895-overwrite-default-snippets/) on ST2's userecho. I added my upvote; you should too!

Comment: Yeah I saw that question on the Sublime forum but thought I'd ask here since no one had replied to him.